# Amazon Redshift: ERROR: 3F000: schema does not exist

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When I go to try to run a very simple query, using a stupid little test db that I set up in postgres testing out amazon's CDC:

```
SELECT * FROM schemastreamtest.testdatatable
```

I get the following:

```
/*
Current path set to $user, public */
/*
ERROR: 3F000: schema "schemastreamtest" does not exist */
SELECT * FROM schemastreamtest.testdatatable;
```

Again, this is not a dummy query, literally called them those, and the data is pushed from postgres to this DB using Data Migration's CDC.

I'm using the Aginity IDE for redshift, and pgAdmin3 for postgres if that matters. The data according to AWS is flowing into it, it just seems to be a retrieval issue.

Comment: when i right click my table and data review > show top 100 it works, but other than that, no.

Comment: select * from pg_namespace where nspname = 'schemastreamtest' gives you it as result? just curios to see

Comment: Does the user has SELECT privilege on this schema? Did you try set search_path to this schema??

Comment: @MiloBellano - it gives nothing

Comment: @hadooper - uh... what? I'm a T-SQL / SSMS DBA who is very new with Redshift & PG.

Comment: First of run `grant select on all tables in schema schemastreamtest to <user_name>;`, then try running `set search_path to schemastreamtest;` this allows the schema to be accessible by the user.

Comment: in aginity right click the table ( the one that you can view 100 rows of) and select "script" then "ddl to new query window". then post what you see as the ddl inside your question above

Comment: @JonScott & hadooper -I was unable to run the grant select for DDL because I get the same error.

Comment: Looks like your user doesn't have proper privileges to access the schema. Request the person who uses the root user for access to your user.

Comment: I made it myself with an account master, which I am logged into.

Comment: Can you please post the result of this query `select * from pg_namespace;`

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database? where exactly is stored schemastreamtest? e.g. my prod database is dev, so my tables are dev.myschema.mytable but I have other db for test purpose, are you connecting in the right place? And also, check you are connecting to the correct cluster. Sometimes I take snapshot with identical tables of production and in Aginity the tables stay there until I click refresh list....

Comment: @hadooper - https://i.imgur.com/LmEU9Cs.png is the results from that.

Comment: @MiloBellano - there's only the one database, sadly

Comment: @dragos_kai I don't see any schema with name schemastreamtest in the list you shared. Did you even create the scheme ??

Comment: ...yes @hadooper I'm sure. For some reason half of what I have in my schema list isn't there. https://i.imgur.com/kEeK98f.png

Comment: If you right click on schema, click on refresh list object, is it still there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloaded the db and it refreshed the schema and it works now.